Functional derivative of gauge fixing condition - Peskin QFT page 295
In Peskin QFT book page 295 it is said that:
$$\det(\delta G(A^\alpha)/ \delta \alpha) = \det(\partial^2/e)\tag{p.295}$$
where $$G(A^\alpha) = \partial^\mu A_\mu^\alpha = \partial^\mu A_\mu + (1/e)\partial^2\alpha.\tag{p.295}$$
Although from the formula from wiki it seems like the functional derivative is $0$ since:
$$\delta G(A^\alpha)/ \delta \alpha = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^\mu \partial x^\nu} \frac{\partial G(A^\alpha)}{\partial (\frac{\partial^2 \alpha}{\partial x^\mu \partial x^\nu})} =\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^\mu \partial x^\nu} 1 = 0.\tag{1} $$
What am I missing?

That’s not how variational derivatives work.

Indeed, that is not how to functionally differentiate... Hint : $\det(\partial^2/e)$ is a short-hand notation for $\det(e^{-1}\partial^2 \delta^{(4)}(x,y))$. Also, where on the wiki did you see your weird formula?

@JeanbaptisteRoux Thanks for the hint. I added a link in my post see there. It seems like this formula is irrelevant to my case and this is why I get this answer.

Hints:

Functional/variational differentiation
$$\frac{\delta\alpha(x)}{\delta\alpha(y)}=\delta^4(x\!-\!y)$$
here acts on different/independent spacetime points $x$ and $y$; not the same spacetime point.

So OP's eq. (1) should read
$$\frac{\delta G(A^{\alpha})(x)}{\delta\alpha(y)}~=~\ldots~=~\frac{1}{e}\partial^2\delta^4(x\!-\!y).\tag{1'}$$


